# Read empty lines C++

Tags: c++, input

I am having trouble reading and differentiating empty lines from an input.

Here's the sample input:

```
 number

 string
 string
 string
 ...

 number

 string
 string
 ...
```

Each number represents the start of an input and the blank line after the sequence of strings represents the end of an input. The string can be a phrase, not only one word.

My code does the following:

```
  int n;

  while(cin >> n) { //number

    string s, blank;
    getline(cin, blank); //reads the blank line

    while (getline(cin, s) && s.length() > 0) { //I've tried !s.empty()
        //do stuff
    }
  }
```

I've tried directly cin >> blank, but it didn't work.

Can someone help me solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You could have read the sequence from just `cin` right? Because it ignores all the blank spaces. So there is no need of reading blanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you read the number with this line:

```
while(cin >> n) { //number
```

`cin` doesn't read anything after the last digit. That means cin's input buffer still contains the rest of the line that the number was on. So, you need to skip that line, *and* the next blank line. You could do that by just using getline twice. i.e.

```
while(cin >> n) { //number

    string s, blank;
    getline(cin, blank); // reads the rest of the line that the number was on
    getline(cin, blank); // reads the blank line

    while (getline(cin, s) && !s.empty()) {
        //do stuff
    }
  }
```

Comment: Isnt it because getLine() stops at seeing a whitespace character. So 1st getLine() will consume the whitespace character and the 2nd getLine() will consume the blank line. The solution given is anyways correct.

Comment: why then continuous prompting for a number doesn't result in a `cin` error; only after the last one, an empty string passed to the next `cin`? for example, if i `cin >> n` three times in a row, then `cin >> string`, the string will be empty, but the previous `cin`s didn't trigger a failure